# C# - How to use webrequest to mimic a curl call

Tags: c#, curl, google-api, webrequest

I have this curl request which I've been able to cobble together from various tutorials, and it works, but I need to be able to do it in C#.

curl -k -d "code=4/blahBLMUeFewxYi7AblahgdBf_7Lm.IrGYEyuzz8QfOl05ti8ZT3bppze2bgI&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=blahjf5z45yLNIjXGSO&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

I have no code to look at, as I have no idea where to start.

Does anyone have any tutorial on how to do just this?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd use "System.Diagnostics.Process" and simply exec a copy of curl...

Comment: This will be running on a shared host. It won't have curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been using [the WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) so far?  That would seem to be a sensible place to start.

If you're looking to do OAuth integration, [there are client libraries for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking of using.  I want to use REST so I can understand what those client libraries do.